# Measuring analog voltage from multiple differential input causes voltage fluctuation

Tags: power-supply, analog, adc, design, differential

[image: Micro-controller with analog connections]

As shown above i am using a micro controller's differential input to measure the analog voltage. When the the micro controller measures the voltage on the input pins there is a voltage fluctuation along with a voltage drop on each of the analog inputs.
What could the possible reasons be for this.The above diagram is not the final design and I need to scale it up for multiple controller. A design limitation prevents me from using buffer based solutions to the issue, even impedance matching cannot be done.
Any suggestion would be greatly helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: source impedance too high for uC input impedance. Buffers must be used, there is no alternative, apart from a different uC with higher input impedance, or a different source with a lower output impedance.

Comment: @Neil_UK Thanks, I will follow up if I find a solution.